# Dockerコンテナ内の一般ユーザに環境変数を渡す方法

Tags: docker, bash

Dockerコンテナ内の一般ユーザに環境変数を渡す方法を探しています。
具体的には以下のような状況です。

---

Dockerコンテナ内に一般ユーザーを作成し、そのユーザによって実行されるべきコマンドがあります。

今の所コンテナの起動コマンドは以下のようになっています。

```sh
docker run -it --rm  --entrypoint su イメージ名 - 一般ユーザ -c "コマンド"
```

で、このコマンドに新たな環境変数を渡したいのですが、以下の要求があります。

- 環境変数は実行環境ごとに異なるので、イメージ内のファイルには書き込めない
- イメージ内の `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` `/etc/profile` `/etc/bashrc` にはすでに大量の設定が書かれており、それらはそのまま使いたい
- 環境変数を設定し `コマンド` を呼び出すためのスクリプトを `-v` オプションで渡す、というのは避けたい
- 渡す環境変数は複数あるので、できれば以下の形は避けたい

  ```sh
  docker run -it --rm  --entrypoint su イメージ名 - 一般ユーザ -c "変数=値 コマンド"
  ```

何か方法はあるでしょうか。
何卒ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この Docker イメージを最初から一般ユーザーとして実行する想定なのであれば、イメージを作る際、つまり Dockerfile の時点から一般ユーザーを作って一般ユーザーとして立ち上がるようにしておくのがよくあるやり方です。この方法であれば環境変数も普通の [`ENV` 命令](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)で与えられます。

つまり、`useradd` & `groupadd` などお使いの OS に準拠したやり方でユーザーを追加し、[`USER` 命令](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)でそのユーザーとしてログインするように指定すれば良いです。

英語版の関連質問: [How to add user with dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39855304/5989200)

Comment: USER命令でイメージのデフォルトのユーザを指定できるのですね。知りませんでした。デフォルトユーザを一般ユーザにした上で `-e` オプションで環境変数を渡すことにしました。ありがとうございました。